# AWS: APIGateway custom response regex fails to match

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I am trying to send a API Gateway Response code of 401 if the user is missing required fields in header. The response from my lambda is as follows:

```
{
    "status": "Unauthorized user",
    "body": ["username"]
}
```

In the AWS API Gateway -> myAPI -> resource -> PUT operation -> Integration Response, I have 2 entries. 

1. For all success with default RegEx Pattern (blank) --> Method response status of 201

2. For regex matching, if I use above JSON and below regex using regex or online regex101.com, there is a full match.

```
.*\"Unauthorized user\".*
```

[image]
[image]
However, the same fails during Test of API with below message

```
<date_time in UTC> : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"status": "Unauthorized user", "body": ["username"] }
<date_time in UTC> : Execution failed due to configuration error: No match for output mapping and no default output mapping configured. Endpoint Response Status Code: 200
<date_time in UTC> : Method completed with status: 500
```

Has anybody faced this? I end up getting a 201 if I have 201 with blank regex... irrespective of Unauthorized or internal error or bad requests.

Comment: Yes; After re-reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html) I even tried setting the regex to .* which it warns will essentially make it the default response. And I still get 200s instead of error codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the image from your question:

[image]

Notice how the header of the first column says `Lambda Error Regex`? That means that API Gateway will only try to match that regex with an error returned by the Lambda. But how does the API Gateway know whether the Lambda returned a genuine response or an error? It knows this based on whether the Lambda `return`ed a response or `threw` an exception.

**Your regex isn't matching because you returned the response instead of throwing it as an exception!**

Check this out:

When my Node.js Lambda does this:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        "status": "Unauthorized user",
        "body": ["username"]
    }
    return response
}
```

My API gateway does this:

[image]

But when the same Lambda does this:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const error = {
        "status": "Unauthorized user",
        "body": ["username"]
    }
    throw JSON.stringify(error)
}
```

The API Gateway does this:

[image]

Comment: This definitely was part of the answer for me. Ultimately there appeared to be something else as .* didn't work as expected, but when I used a regex that would find the whole line of an error message it started working as expected.